# Assigning a list of lists as a nested column

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I want to use purrr to generate some data based on some parameters.

Shown below is a script that will generate a beta density on 0 to 1 parametedized by a `a` and `b` (the columns of the dataframe `params`.

```
library(tidyverse)

a = c(2,4,6)
b = c(10,12,14)

params = expand.grid(a = a, b = b)

gen_den = function(a,b){ 
  x = seq(0,1,0.1)
  den = dbeta(x = x, shape1 = a, shape2 = b)

  return(den)
  }

# Want to assign this as a nested column
 params %>% 
  pmap(gen_den)
```

I was wondering if I could assign the results of the `pmap` to a column, where each observation is a nested data frame.  Shown below is some desired output.  Here, the `data` column is the output from `gen_den(a,b)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is

```
 params %>% 
   mutate(den = pmap(params, gen_den))
```

I myself just recently asked [a tangentially related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587951) and can now also give you some variant syntaxes to the same end that you may find useful:

```
 params %>% 
    {mutate(., den = pmap(., gen_den))}
```

This version might look better if you don't like having to type `params` more than once.

Comment: Why not just `map`, since there's only one function?